# How do i implement both built-in django auth and third party social-auth in my application?

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, django-rest-framework

I using django from last 4-5 months and recently started learning django-rest-framework and I'm confused about proper authentication system,
Actually I am trying to build an application mostly using REST API because my 
client can be both browser and Android, 
so I need an authentication system in which user can sign up using both django
built-in auth(django.contrib.auth.model.User) as well as third-party social
authentication(Google, Facebook, etc..).

Now, I'm confused about how do I create my database, because when ever i'll create
a table/model lets say a 'Book', then this model would need a foreign key to the user model and here user can be both 'django.contrib.auth.model.User' and a user signed-up using third party auth,

So how I will refer to User in foreign key Field of my models?

And I have also decided to customize django's buit-in auth because i want
user to login using their email not username.

```
class Book(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(...)
  author = models.ForeignKey(?) ? Here, how do i refer to both
                                 'django.contrib...User' and users signed-up                     
                                 using thrid-party auth.
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me elaborate on your question.
First of all: You're lucky. There's an (almost) out of the box version for your problem.

For social and normal authentication and registration, including email verification etc. you can rely on django-allauth:

https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth

django-restauth provides a restful platform built on top of all-auth, so that you don't even have to start building your auth rest api from scratch:

https://github.com/Tivix/django-rest-auth

When it comes to your db schema, there are a few options. You could go ahead and build your own authentication system, which, in my opinion, is overkill. 
Rather more, I would implement a profile model, which has a OneToOne relationship to the User model from django.contrib.auth.models.User as described in [this chapter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model%22this%22) of the Django docs.

Your models (of course in separated apps) would look like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
#other imports

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    books_read = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    books_recommended = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(...)
    author = models.ForeignKey('UserProfile', related_name='books')
```

Another question you will run into is how to update and/or display those nested relations in your serializers.

[This FAQ article](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html%22asd%22) from the django-restauth docs and [this chapter](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships%22this%22) of the official django-rest_framework docs will get you jumpstarted.

Best,
D

Comment: Thanks Deniz, but I'm confused about what I'll store in 'user' field of UserProfile(According to your answer), when user register them self with social authentication.

Comment: You will store a reference to the auth user model from django.contrib.auth.models! Think of it as a separation of concerns. All the auth part is done by djangos user and the user profile ist dealing with additional information! Django all auth will handle all your social login / normal login and will link it to the auth model. Token handling included :)

Comment: Ok, all-auth can even handle my normal auth, I didn't knew that, that's why I was confused..I was thinking I'll have to handle my own auth separately from third-party auth system.

Comment: Right, it relies on the included auth system. If you check out the docs you'll find a configuration section where you'll find settings you can include in your settings file to change the default behavior. Rest auth provides the necessary serializers etc to make all auth restful